# Reverse proxy just the homepage

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy

I am trying to reverse proxy just the homepage on a website - trying to use the rules below.  Basically I have an alternate page that I want the content to be server from but I still want the original URL for the site to display with the content from the reverse proxy.  Both pages are in the same domain - the only difference is one is www.domain.com while the other page is www2.domain.com

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
ProxyPass http://www.domain.com http://www2.domain.com/
ProxyPassReverse http://www.domain.com  http://www2.domain.com/
```

When I put in rules above it does not work - can somebody show where Im going wrong please ?

Comment: RewriteCond has no effect on proxying rules, it's only used for mod_rewrite rules. So you can remove that line completely if you're going to be using mod_proxy. It would also be helpful for you to explain what exactly happens - do your rules not have any effect at all, or do they do something but not what you expect?

Comment: I though to had to put in the RewriteCond becuase I only want the reverse proxy to happen on the front page e.g. www.domain.com and NOT on anything else e.g. www.domain.com/sales etc ....When I put the rules in nothing happens at all and the front page is still served from its original location - not the proxied one ....hope ive explained this better .... thanks for your time ...

Answer (score 1):

The first argument for [ProxyPass](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) and [ProxyPassReverse](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse) is a path, the correct syntax for your directives would be

```
ProxyPass / http://www2.domain.com/
ProxyPassReverse /  http://www2.domain.com/
```

But that would proxy all your requests. Try

```
#disable forward requests
ProxyRequests Off

#allow proxy requests
<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

#reverse proxy 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^/?$   http://www2.domain.com/ [P,QSA,L]
```

If the proxying fails, you server error.log may tell you what happens. Or add a log for the mod_rewrite, it will tell you why it doesn't capture the request

```
RewriteLogLevel 5
RewriteLog /path/to/a/file
```

Comment: Thanks for your help ....I have tried this but it is not working - When I put the rules in I am prompted for username and password from the old site as if its reading a htaccess file from the old site and not pulling the content from the proxied new site ...

Comment: @frodo You will have to inspect what your server does. I added some tips to do that.